# DropDownList selected is not set

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a view where i use DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Nationality, NationalityDD, new { style = "width:185px;" })
```

SelectListItem List is reneged following way :

```
List<SelectListItem> NationalityDD = new List<SelectListItem>();
var n0 = new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "" };
var n1 = new SelectListItem { Value = "p", Text = @Resources.Localization.nationality_LR_citizen };
var n2 = new SelectListItem { Value = "np", Text = @Resources.Localization.nationality_LR_resident };
var n3 = new SelectListItem { Value = "es", Text = @Resources.Localization.nationality_ES_citizen };
var n4 = new SelectListItem { Value = "ne", Text = @Resources.Localization.nationality_other };

NationalityDD.Add(n0); NationalityDD.Add(n1); NationalityDD.Add(n2); NationalityDD.Add(n3); NationalityDD.Add(n4);
```

So, the issue is that when I set np/es/ne values into database, after refreshing page everything is fine and selected values are still shown, but if I set `p` after page is refreshed there is no selected value "".

This html is generated by DDL when I choose `p` (after refresh):

```
<select id="Nationality" name="Nationality" style="width:185px;">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="p">LR pilsonis</option>
<option value="np">LR Pastāvīgais iedzīvotājs</option>
<option value="es">ES pilsonis</option>
<option value="ne">ne-ES pilsonis</option>
</select>
```

and when I select something except `p` (after refresh):

```
<select id="Nationality" name="Nationality" style="width:185px;"><option value=""></option>
<option value="p">LR pilsonis</option>
<option value="np">LR Pastāvīgais iedzīvotājs</option>
<option selected="selected" value="es">ES pilsonis</option>
<option value="ne">ne-ES pilsonis</option>
</select>
```

What could be the reason of such a strange behavior of DDL?

Comment: Where is your code which sets the selected option (when you refresh/page loads) ?

Comment: Does not dropdown list do it on his own?

Comment: No you need to write code to set it ? Use `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method

Comment: What do you mean? First value `m => m.Nationality` is equal to one element in DDL, so it has to be the chosen option?

Comment: are you setting the value of `Nationality` property in your code before returning to the view ? You should do that. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937361/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-not-populating-selectedvalue/11937514#11937514

Comment: Yeah I do, I have a model with all values set. And I get right values in a view (while debugging) but in this only case with `p` selected ddl just rejects to choose it, but it is in list of its options and in a model -> Nationality field it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was too stupid.. In database I am using the Nationality field was created not nvarchar(2), but simple char(2), so in case of  `nationality_LR_citizen = p` it was space left, so the `p`== `p` was false and DDLF did not select this value.